# delete primary key row which is foreign key of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Suppose there is a main table containing a primary key and there is another table which contains a foreign key to this main table. So if we delete the row of main table only not child table.

Comment: If you leave the record in the child, it's an orphan -- broken referential integrity...

Comment: Research `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't Jeopardy - could you please restate your question in the form of a question?

Comment: Not sure about what exactly you are looking for, hope this will help. 
If you have the foreign key define, you would not be able to delete the parent record, untill you delete its child.
So first you have to delete the child data and then only you can delete data from main table.

Answer (score 9):

You should set some specific options on your FKey, such as ON DELETE {CASCADE, SET NULL, SET DEFAULT}

Instead you'll not be able to delete referenced row, because it is prohibited by sql server due to referrential integrity.

So, the option is to set referencing table's value to NULL or any other DEFAULT value.

**Or** delete it too

**Or**, if your referencing row has some meaning without parent row - then **something is wrong with your DB design** - either you do not need the FKey or schema is not normalized.

Comment: The last paragraph is very important. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this

```
ALTER TABLE MainTable
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_xyz  
FOREIGN KEY (xyz)  
REFERENCES ChildTable (xyz) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Not working ..!!
i deleted the primary key row and still i can see foreign key table holding the row.

Answer (score 1):

i think u want some thing like this.

ON DELETE CASCADE
    Specifies that if an attempt is made to delete a row with a key referenced by foreign keys in existing rows in other tables, all rows that contain those foreign keys are also deleted.

ref:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973%28SQL.90%29.aspx