# delete primary key row which is foreign key of another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [delete primary key row which is foreign key of another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982172/delete-primary-key-row-which-is-foreign-key-of-another-table)

Table `Customers`:

```
CustomerID
```

Table `Addresses`:

```
AddressId
```

Table `Customers_Addresses`

```
CustomerID
AddressID
```

Table `Customer_person`

```
CustomerID
PersonID
```

I want to delete a row from the `Customer` table identified by a `CustomerID`, and I want to update the `Addresses` and `customer_person` tables.

How can I create such a query? Please help me.

Comment: Instead of asking a new question, edit your old question to make it understandable. You may find ["Writing the Perfect Question"](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) a helpful guideline. Also, instead of using an ad-hoc schema, use actual [sample code](http://sscce.org/) (SQL statements) for the table schema and sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Cascading Deletes](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/defining-cascading-referential-integrity-constraints-in-sql-server/128) will accomplish your goal with ease.

Answer (score 0):

You should set some specific options on your FKey, such as ON DELETE {CASCADE, SET NULL, SET DEFAULT}

Instead you'll not be able to delete referenced row, because it is prohibited by sql server due to referrential integrity.

So, the option is to set referencing table's value to NULL or any other DEFAULT value.

**Or** delete it too

**Or**, if your referencing row has some meaning without parent row - then **something is wrong with your DB design** - either you do not need the FKey or schema is not normalized.

Answer (score -1):

you should not delete your records, instead use this approach.  make one column called "isDeleted" with Boolean data-type. default values is "false". now whenever you want to delete any records just make that record "true". Make change In your select query to select only those records which are `isDeleted = false;`

Comment: You're introducing business logic that wasn't specified. Further, the datatype is `bit`, and not boolean. Why not use a datetime instead? Why not use a varchar to indicate the user who deleted?