# How to delete a row from Parent table without delete a row from Child table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Am having parent table which has foreign three foreign key but i want to delete row in parent table alone ,how to achieve it ??
The query that am using currently is

```
DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ColumnName= '89416'
```

The query show error:  `Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Comment: Don't do it! You can drop foreign keys for the time being and drop from parent row, but this will create orphan records which is a bad thing.

Comment: Well, that's why it's called Referential Integrity, it's used to prevent such stupid things :-)

Comment: i think you can SET foreign_key_checks = 0;

Comment: If we are deleting parent, Why that should be associated to a child..??? Just break the association then perform deletion if u want... Which is not recommendable anyway..

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982172/delete-primary-key-row-which-is-foreign-key-of-another-table

Answer (score 1):

You should rework on your requirement, we maintain parent child relation table relation because we need that connected data .

But anyway if you want to delete , then one option is there(Disable Constraints and then enable after delete). But again it will give a problem .

Answer (score 0):

Change your child table by creating it as shown in the sample below:

```
CREATE TABLE Worker (
 WorkerID smallint auto_increment,
 WorkerType  varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 WorkerName  varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 Position    varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 TaxFileNumber int NOT NULL,
 Address    varchar(100) ,
 Phone      varchar(20) ,
 SupervisorID  smallint ,
 PRIMARY KEY (WorkerID),
 FOREIGN KEY (SupervisorID) REFERENCES Worker(WorkerID)
    ON DELETE SET NULL
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

You just add `ON DELETE SET NULL` or `NO ACTION`. Before use, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163301/mysql-workbench-foreign-key-options-restrict-cascade-set-null-no-action-wh#answer-16163382) on a similar question, that explains the different behaviors.